# Concerns with WCF Data Services and outdated references

Tags: .net, wcf-data-services, versioning, legacy-code

I am looking for information on how well [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106) handle being called when they're referenced by an application with an out dated service reference..

If all new added fields are allowed to be `null` and we're not breaking any existing links for objects, is there anything else we need to be aware of when hosting a WCF Data Service that is still under development and will often be called to using outdated references (from 3rd parties).

Answer (score 0):

For those who are wondering, not sure how I missed it in all my searches but I found my answer here:

[Data Service Versioning (WCF Data Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee473427.aspx)

**Entity property changes.**

**Requires a new version:**

- Remove existing property or relationship
- Add non-nullable property
- Change existing property

**New version not needed:**

- Add nullable property

With the additional note:

> You can set the `IgnoreMissingProperties` property to true to have the
>   client ignore any new properties sent by the data service that are not
>   defined on the client. However, when inserts are made, the properties
>   not included by the client in the POST request are set to their
>   default values. For updates, any existing data in a property unknown
>   to the client might be overwritten with default values. In this case,
>   you should send the update as a MERGE request, which is the default.
>   For more information, see Managing the Data Service Context (WCF Data
>   Services).

So provided you only add nullable properties you don't need to be concerned with versioning complications with your WCF Data Service.